# How to change the url sent to an html form?

Tags: html, forms

Suppose we have:

```
 <form action="xxx">
     <input type="checkbox" id = "checkbox" name="checked" value="1">
     <input type="submit">Submit</input>
 </form>"
```

When click the submit button, the url should be something like "xxx?checked=1". In this case, I want to append another parameter to the url. I know using hidden value is an option, but do we have a more direct way? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with a hidden input?  In most normal situations it would be a very proper solution to the problem.

Comment: are you doing any jquery processing already ?

Comment: @BradKoch I know a hidden parameter is a good solution in most cases. But in my application it's causing some other bug on IE due to some unknown reason.

Comment: @karthikr If you have some idea other than hidden params, can you please give a simple example? Thanks

Comment: IE should handle hidden inputs perfectly fine, what issue are you seeing?

Comment: @Ricky - Check the answer - not sure if you want the jquery approach though. I dint see jquery tagged part of the question.

Comment: @BradKoch. Thank you first. I simplified the situation so that you can understand my question. Actually we want that additional parameters to be passed in certain condition. With a hidden parameter, it will be passed to the url in IE anyway(in other browsers, everything is OK). That's why I'm seeking for an alter.

Answer (score 3):

The fact is the url depends on the method you are using to send the form. This is set on [the `method` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) on [the `<form>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp).

The URL of the `action` can be any valid URL so to add extra attributes like `something=1` and `other=2` you could set the following:

```
<form action="xxx?something=1&other=2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checked" value="1">
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

submitting the form will now send the `GET` request `xxx?something=1&other=2&checked=1`

Comment: What I've tried is: $('form').attr('action', "xxx?&something=1"); but looks like things behind "?" is removed by the browser.

Comment: So you need to change the url through javascript before submitting the form?